# Project Euler # 38 Pandigital multiples in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

> Take the number 192 and multiply it by each of 1, 2, and 3:
>
> - 192 × 1 = 192
> - 192 × 2 = 384
> - 192 × 3 = 576
>
> By concatenating each product we get the 1 to 9 pandigital, 192384576. We will call 192384576 the concatenated product of 192 and (1,2,3)
>
> The same can be achieved by starting with 9 and multiplying by 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, giving the pandigital, 918273645, which is the concatenated product of 9 and (1,2,3,4,5).
>
> What is the largest 1 to 9 pandigital 9-digit number that can be formed as the concatenated product of an integer with (1,2, ... , n) where n > 1?

Awaiting feedback.

```
def check_pandigital(n):
    """Assumes n is a string of numbers.
    returns True if 1-9 in number, False otherwise."""
    for i in range(1, 9):
        if str(i) not in n:
            return False
    return True


def multiply_concatenate(n):
    """Assumes n is a positive integer.
    returns concatenations of number multiplied by a range if (1-9) in number."""
    s = str(n)
    for i in range(2, 10):
        s += str(i * n)
        if check_pandigital(s):
            return s


def check_range(n):
    """Assumes n is a range(integer).
    generates pandigitals within the range."""
    for i in range(2, n):
        mult_conc = multiply_concatenate(i)
        if mult_conc and len(mult_conc) <= 9:
            yield mult_conc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(max(int(number) for number in check_range(10000)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## use builtins

```
def check_pandigital(n): ...
    for i in range(1, 9):
        if str(i) not in n:
            return False
    return True
```

Didn't we want the `high` value to be `10` rather than `9`?

This is `return all(str(i) in n  for i in range(1, high))`

## use type annotations

Syntactically, telling the machine about type is optional.

Semantically, telling humans about type tends to be pretty important.
If I attempt to evaluate `"kitchen sink" + 1`,
it's unlikely something good will happen.

```
def check_pandigital(n):
    """Assumes n is a string of numbers.
    returns True if ... """
```

[Pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
suggests that you name it `is_pandigital`,
so the Gentle Reader will know the return type is `bool`.

The initial English sentence is nice enough.
But it is verbose.
And `mypy`, for all its cleverness, cannot read it.
Consider the audiences you're trying to reach,
and then please address them in a way they'll all understand.

You could have introduced the function with:

```
def check_pandigital(n: str) -> bool:
```

Then I could read a shorter docstring.
And `mypy` could alert us to inappropriate call sequences.

Similarly for `def multiply_concatenate(n: int) -> str:`

Once relieved of the tedium of describing in / out types,
your docstrings would be free to focus on their
essential purpose, which is to describe a
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).
When I read a concise single-sentence docstring,
the one thing I'm hoping to learn is: What does it *promise*?
What will be true upon `return`?
Hopefully it's specific enough that,
given arbitrary (valid) input,
a unit test could evaluate whether it's a correct answer or not.

## pass a range

This call is nice enough: `check_range(10_000)`

Notice that, if you want, you could declare a signature of

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def check_range(rng: range) -> Iterable[str]:
```

and then use `for i in rng:`
The call site would invoke `check_range(range(2, 10_000))`

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

The code layout is good, the code is compact, and the functions
have docstrings.

### Lint check

[pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html) identified a couple issues.

The `multiply_concatenate` function does not explicitly `return`
under all conditions.  Since it sometimes returns `None`, it would be good
to explicitly do so.

The short variable names `n` and `s` could be given more meaningful names.

### Naming

Some of the function and variable names could be improved.

`check_pandigital` could be renamed `is_pandigital`, which is a customary
name for function that return a boolean value.

Its input `n` implies that it is a numerical value, but it is really a string
consisting of integers.  Consider renaming it as `string_of_nums`.

The other 2 functions do have numeric input.  Consider renaming them from
`n` to `num`.

The `check_range` name is too generic, and I don't understand what
"range" means in this context.

### Documentation

It is great that the functions have docstrings, but I think they can be
improved to better understand the code they are describing.  Since the code
alternates between string and integer representations of the numbers, it
would be helpful to explicitly state what type each function accepts and
returns.  Refer to the code below for alternate docstrings.

---

Here is new code with the suggestions above:

```
def is_pandigital(string_of_nums):
    """
    Input is a string consisting only of numbers, like '6121824'.
    Returns True if all digits (1-9) are in the input string.
    Returns False otherwise.
    """
    for i in range(1, 9):
        if str(i) not in string_of_nums:
            return False
    return True

def multiply_concatenate(num):
    """
    Input is a positive integer.
    Multiplies the input by a range of values (1-9), then concatenates
    the product into a string until the string is determined to be pandigital.
    Returns the pandigital string or None.
    """
    string = str(num)
    for i in range(2, 10):
        string += str(i * num)
        if is_pandigital(string):
            return string
    return None

def check_range(num):
    """
    Input is a positive integer greater than 9.
    Returns list of pandigitals within the range.
    """
    for i in range(2, num):
        mult_conc = multiply_concatenate(i)
        if mult_conc and len(mult_conc) <= 9:
            yield mult_conc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(max(int(number) for number in check_range(10000)))
```